# Strange issue when resolving server SSL certificate within UnitTest in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssl, httpwebrequest

I have a really strange issue when Visual Studio resolves the server SSL certificate.

The API I am using requires me to send a certificate along with the request to 'verify who I am'.  Initially I referred to this certificate within my UnitTest using `X509Certificate2` and then importing it as a `byte[]`.  What I didn't want to do, is have this laying around in my code referring to a specific location on my local disk (I want to run the unit tests automatically on my build server) so opted to install the certificate within the certificate store (which I could later install on the build server). And when I tested this Uri within the browser (IE) it asked for the certificate I wanted to use and rather stupidly I clicked OK without really reading what it was asking me to do.

Problem is, since doing this I am unable to run my unit test (I am making an `HttpWebRequest`) - as soon as it hits the following line it throws a `WebException`.

```
using (var response = request.GetResponse()) 
{
    // Removed content ...
}
```

The exception response is null , here is the exception

> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An
>   unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOException:
>   Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was
>   forcibly closed by the remote host

The only reason I can see for this error is that Visual Studio is using the wrong SSL certificate for the server connection (as I am using the test API Uri, I can verify this is sort of the case by using the live API Uri which works fine)

I have tried the following:

- Removing the certificate from the store
- Adding the certificate back to the store
- Clearing all browser cache
- Restoring IE back to 'factory settings'
- Clearing the SSL cache within IE
- Tried setting Keepalive to true and then false

This issue was affecting all browsers but I have managed to get it working.  I have tried to use Fiddler to identify if the server is doing something crazy (including decrypting SSL connections) and I can see this is actually responding with a 403 error.

Has anyone else got any ideas?

Edit

Just tried to run this on the build server, still get the same error so I will check with the API provider to see if a/ my certificate has expired b/ their service is actually up!

> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An
>   unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOException:
>   Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was
>   forcibly closed by the remote host

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with the API provider.